# C warning when using sprintf to fill struct member

Tags: struct, printf

I'm trying to fill out a `char array` from a `struct pointer`.
It works but I get this warning:
`warning: passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct match {
    char* weekday[4];
} match;

int main() {
    char* line = "Mon\0";
    match* match;

    sprintf(match->weekday, "%s", line);
    printf("%s", match->weekday);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is `match->weekday`an incompatible pointer type?

Comment: The first argument of `sprintf` should have type `char *` but you pass `char *[4]`.  Instead you should provide a `char` buffer to write into

Comment: Of course, thanks